# Set a different color for each day (widget)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, widget

I am rewriting this widget and I want to set a color for each day of the week, like `Monday = blue`, `Tuesday = purple`, etc. So that each day will be displayed on the screen of the selected color.

I have searched online but I haven’t found nothing that would help me. I tried different methods as `getDay()`, `getElementsByTagName`, `var colors`, `if/else`, but those didn’t worked (probably because I did something wrong)

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lockplus.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Config.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="screenElements">
</div>
<img id="wallpaper" src="" width="320"/>
<div class="screenOverlay"></div>
<img class='svg' style="display:none; opacity:0;"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/svg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/clock.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/weather.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/stats.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/misc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
  if (window.innerWidth === 375) {
      document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=0');
  } else if (window.innerWidth === 414) {
      document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=0');
  }
}());
</script>
</body>
</html>


—- LOCKPLUS.js ——
var dev='LockPlus';var wIcon ='';var wallpaper=null;var overlay=null;
var elements={
  "day":{
    "z-index":2,
    "font-family":"alpine",
    "color":"white",
    "position":"absolute",
    "font-size":"38px",
    "top":"52px",
    "left":0,
    "width":"320px",
    "text-align":"center",
    "text-shadow":"rgb(0,0,0) 1px 2px 2px"
  },
  "zclock":{
    "z-index":2,
    "color":"white",
    "font-family":"bebasbold",
    "position":"absolute",
    "font-size":"25px",
    "top":"101px",
    "left":0,
    "width":"320px",
    "text-align":"center",
    "text-shadow":"rgb(0, 0,0) 1px 2px 2px"
  },
  "datemonth":{
    "z-index":2,
    "color":"white",
    "font-family":"alpine",
    "position":"absolute",
    "font-size":"23px",
    "top":122,
    "left":0,
    "width":"320px",
    "text-align":"center",
     "text-shadow":"rgb(0,0,0) 1px 2px 2px"
  },
  "boxOne":{
    "width":"50px",
    "height":"1px",
    "background-color":"rgba(255,255,255,0.73)",
    "z-index":1,
    "border-color":"red",
    "border-style":"solid",
    "border-width":"0px",
    "position":"absolute",
    "top":"117px",
    "left":"186px"
  },
    "boxTwo":{
    "width":"50px",
    "height":"1px",
    "background-color":"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.73)",
    "z-index":1,
    "border-color":"red",
    "border-style":"solid",
    "border-width":"0px",
    "position":"absolute",
    "top":"117px",
    "left":"82px"
  },
  "boxThree":{
    "width":"30px",
    "height":"1px",
    "background-color":"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.73)",
    "z-index":1,
    "border-color":"red",
    "border-style":"solid",
    "border-width":"0px",
    "position":"absolute",
    "top":"105px",
    "left":"186px"
  },
  "boxFour":{
    "width":"30px",
    "height":"1px",
    "background-color":"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.73)",
    "z-index":1,
    "border-color":"red",
    "border-style":"solid",
    "border-width":"0px",
    "position":"absolute",
    "top":"105px",
    "left":103
  }
};
```

Can you help me? Do you think is possible? What would be the right way to make it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit shady, and it's using few libraries. Here is a plain html/css/js example achieving what you want:

```js
const daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
const backgrounds = [
  {
    name: 'Sunday',
    color: 'red'
  }, {
    name: 'Monday',
    color: 'blue'
  }, {
    name: 'Tuesday',
    color: 'green'
  }, {
    name: 'Wednesday',
    color: 'yellow'
  }, {
    name: 'Thursday',
    color: 'orange'
  }, {
    name: 'Friday',
    color: 'purple'
  }, {
    name: 'Saturday',
    color: 'brown'
  }
];
const todayDayNumber = new Date().getDay();
const todayDayName = daysOfWeek[todayDayNumber];
const todayColor = backgrounds.find(day => day.name === todayDayName).color;

document.getElementById("todayText").innerHTML = todayDayName;
document.getElementById("todayText").style.color = todayColor;
```

```css
#todayText {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Today is:</p>
<div id='todayText'></div>
```

Comment: This changes the background color, not the text unfortunately. Maybe code is a bit shady cause widget has clock, calendar, weather, etc?

Comment: I have udpdated my answer. Now it is changing text color. You have posted whole app :) It is best to post only fragments that are causing you problems. Anyways, put your working code [here(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net) and I will take a look.